# Is it possible to automate route creation?

Tags: routes, laravel-8, vuejs3

I want to create a way where I will just add route details in a table, extract the information from that table, and put the result to `routes`. Is it possible?

In the long run, the `routes` will get longer and longer which means that everytime a new feature or module will be added, I have to edit the `routes.js` again and again, so I just want to automate its creation.

example routes.js

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";

const routes = [
    {
        name: "login",
        path: "/login",
        component: Login,
    },
    {
        name: "dashboard",
        path: "/dashboard",
        component: Dashboard,
    },
];


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})

export default router;
```

Comment: Some meta-frameworks like Nuxt.js or Vitesse help with that. Otherwise, you can have some helper function which makes it easier.

Comment: [`vite-plugin-pages`](https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages) seems to do exactly that if you are using vite, but I have no clue how to get it started, currently looking for a way.